# Claudia.js create cannot find module lambda in typescript project

Tags: amazon-web-services, typescript, aws-lambda, claudiajs, claudia.js

After searching for hours I can't figure out how to properly run **claudia create** in my project.

Following [this turoial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/express-js-and-aws-lambda-a-serverless-love-story-7c77ba0eaa35), I created a group and a user the AWS console, then I added the keys to my **.aws/credentials** file.

Then I ran this command that correctly produced the lambda.js file :

> claudia --source dist generate-serverless-express-proxy --express-module app

My **lambda.js**

```
'use strict'
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express')
const app = require('./app')
const binaryMimeTypes = [
    'application/octet-stream',
    'font/eot',
    'font/opentype',
    'font/otf',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/svg+xml'
]
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app, null, binaryMimeTypes);
exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context)
```

Then I tried to deploy the lambda function on AWS :

> claudia create --source dist --profile myprofile --handler lambda.handler --deploy-proxy-api --region eu-west-1

But I got this error :

> validating package TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
>       at _addListener (events.js:239:11)
>       at Server.addListener (events.js:297:10)
>       at new Server (_http_server.js:269:10)
>       at Object.createServer (http.js:34:10)
>       at Object.createServer (/tmp/IiRPif/my-project-1.0.0-1Yh6Wb/package/node_modules/aws-serverless-express/index.js:155:25)
>       at Object. (/tmp/IiRPif/my-project-1.0.0-1Yh6Wb/package/lambda.js:13:37)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at validatePackage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/claudia/src/tasks/validate-package.js:16:15)
>       at initEnvVarsFromOptions.then.then.then.then.then.then.then.dir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/claudia/src/commands/create.js:342:10)
>       at  cannot require ./lambda after clean installation. Check your dependencies.

What am I doing wrong here ?

My **package.json**

```
{ 
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json & cp \"package.json\" \"dist/package.json\"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "homepage": "...",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

My **app.ts**

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Routes } from "./routes/routes";

class App {

    public app: express.Application;
    public routes: Routes = new Routes();

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();

        // Parser setup
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

        this.routes.routes(this.app);            
    }
}

exports.default = new App().app;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a [discussion on Claudia's github](https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia/issues/163), this appears to be a compatibility issue between es6 and claudia/lambda.

All I needed to do was to change this line in my **app.js** file from :

```
exports.default = new App().app;
```

To :

```
module.exports = new App().app;
```